# Filtering on a comma separated string by relative position in pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that shows on a row by row basis, the packages a user has active, and whether they use that package on a trial basis using true/false logic.:

```
| User | Packages  | TrialStatus                 |
|------|-----------|-----------------------------|
| 345  | A,B,C,D,F | False,False,False,True,True |
| 238  | B,C,F     | True,False,False            |
| 467  | A,B       | False,True                  |
```

As you can see, the values for columns `packages` and `TrialStatus` are simply comma seperated strings. The position of the true/false values in `TrialStatus` correspoding to the package positions in the `packages` column.

What I would like is an easy way to search the `packages` column for a specific package (e.g. `B`), look in the `TrialStatus` column for the trial status of package `B` and see if it's True based upon the position, and then return the original dataframe with a new column with the trial status of package B only. This should return:

```
| User | Packages  | TrialStatus                 | PackageB_TrialStatus |
|------|-----------|-----------------------------|----------------------|
| 345  | A,B,C,D,F | False,False,False,True,True | False                |
| 238  | B,C,F     | True,False,False            | True                 |
| 467  | A,B       | False,True                  | True                 |
```

My first thought is to combine the usual list comprehension way to create pandas conditional columns:

`df['cond_column'] = ['true' if x == 'true_value' else 'false' for x in df['other_column']]`

and combine this with some regex perhaps for the positional aspect but not sure if this would work. Can anybody please help? let me know if more explanation is needed

Comment: Also include code for creating this dummy data.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a helper dataframe with exploded values, then use it to filter your data and `merge` with the original dataframe:

```
df2 = (df.assign(Packages=df['Packages'].str.split(','),
                 TrialStatus=df['TrialStatus'].str.split(',')
                 )
         # multi-column explode requires pandas ≥ 1.3.0
         # if older use .apply(pd.Series.explode)
         .explode(column=['Packages', 'TrialStatus'])
       )

                             #  .eq('B')   # is also valid
df.merge(df2.loc[df2['Packages'].isin(['B']), ['User', 'TrialStatus']],
         on='User', suffixes=('', '_B')
        )
```

Having the helper dataframe will enable you to efficiently search for other possibilities, instead of repeating the `split` process every time you need to perform this action.

output:

```
   User   Packages                  TrialStatus TrialStatus_B
0   345  A,B,C,D,F  False,False,False,True,True         False
1   238      B,C,F             True,False,False          True
2   467        A,B                   False,True          True
```

Comment: good solution, I see need upgrade pandas.

Comment: Thanks , but this gives me `ValueError: columns must have matching element counts` which I assume means I have 2 lists in a row with different sizes. How would I find out which one it is and solve the error?

Answer (score 0):

By using apply and converting string into list.No need of regex.

```
data = {"User": [345, 238, 467], "Packages": ["A,B,C,D,F", "B,C,F", "A,B"],
    "TrialStatus":["False,False,False,True,True", "True,False,False", "False,True"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Df

| User | Packages | TrialStatus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 345 | A,B,C,D,F | False,False,False,True,True |
| 238 | B,C,F | True,False,False |
| 467 | A,B | False,True |

```
 df["PackageB_TrialStatus"] = df.apply(lambda x: "True" if x["Packages"].split(",").index("B") == x["TrialStatus"].split(",").index("True") else "False", axis=1)
```

Output DF

| User | Packag | TrialStatus | PackageB_TrialStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 345 | A,B,C,D,F | False,False,False,True,True | False |
| 238 | B,C,F | True,False,False | True |
| 467 | A,B | False,True | True |